# function input variation

Tags: c++, function, opencv, input

I am studying some `openCV` document and header and try to fully understand what's going on here.

In `core_c.h`:

```
CVAPI(CvMat*) cvInitMatHeader( CvMat* mat, int rows, int cols,
                          int type, void* data CV_DEFAULT(NULL),
                          int step CV_DEFAULT(CV_AUTOSTEP) );
```

First, in the declaration of `cvInitMatHeader`

```
void* data CV_DEFAULT(NULL),
int step CV_DEFAULT(CV_AUTOSTEP)
```

What does this kind of input variable mean? What's the difference between this and the declaration that we usually use, such as

```
void* data 
int step
```

Second,
I read tutorial that we actually can use cvInitMatHeader by

```
double a[] = { 1,  2,  3,  4,
           5,  6,  7,  8,
           9, 10, 11, 12 };
CvMat Ma;
cvInitMatHeader(&Ma, 3, 4, CV_64FC1, a);
```

the number of input variable is not match with the header, and I cannot find other function overload.

Why is this can work?

Comment: Are you aware of functions with default values for parameters ?

Answer (score 1):

From the code given I can deduce that `CV_DEFAULT(x)` is a macro that expands to `= x`. See [default arguments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_argument) if you are not familiar with them.

Comment: +1 I was writing a Hello World example to explain default arguments. Wiki link explains better :)